# WebView not wraping content

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I can't make my `WebView` wrap the displayed content. The problem is that the `WebView` width is all the screen, while the height is about 300px. How can I make it wrap content and be like the file suppose to be?

Here is my current layout XML:

```
 <WebView
  android:id="@+id/animation_1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Webview** is built to render **HTML** pages which **doesn't have size**. so there is no way for it to determine something that doesn't exist and re-size according to it the same way say an ImageView resizes when the src image has changed.

Your best choice is to set the size of the webview to a fixed value *maybe with weight* and the user will have to scroll inside it when the page is bigger than the webview itself.

Comment: Well, it does at least have a height - setting it to `wrap_content` works, in most cases.

Comment: @User my first page didn't work, height was very small

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this link [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18726)

here it is mention that WebView has bug namely "Wrap content sized webview does not decrease size when the content size decreases"